# How to implement implicit grant flow and read custom claims

Tags: angular, azure-ad-b2c

From my Angular application, I need to call an API which accepts an Azure AD B2C id_token.

Azure AD users are logged into my Angular application.

How do I generate id_token without asking users to login again and include custom claims in the token.

Comment: You cannot achieve this. The Id_token can only generated by Azure AD authenticate endpiont when users sign in and request id_token and code. Each session can only have one id_token.

Comment: Can you please let me know which endpoint I can call to achieve this and what all parameters I need to pass from angular app

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access custom claims from a downstream web API, you'll need to have that API [call the Azure AD Graph via the client_credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet) to query the user object and obtain all of it's properties.

Alternatively, since custom claims are included in the `id_token`. You can pass along the id_token for your Angular app to your web API along with the access token.